# Format Text(Code), removing spaces and stuff

Tags: c#

I want to make it so each code will Always look the same no matter if you use 100 spaces etc.

So for example

```
Example: lwz r4,-0x0018(rtoc)
```

This is how the code should look, and here is examples of how it Could be inputed.

```
lwz   r4,   -0x0018     (rtoc)
lwz       r4,-0x0018(rtoc)
lwz r4,-0x0018   (rtoc)
```

There are other codes as well, but i think the general rule is.

(No Space around",". And "No space around "(" and ")" ).

As this will get looped many times through lines, the method should preferably be quite fast.

I am not against using unsafe code etc:)

Thanks!

EDIT:

Code can also be like: "fmul f0,f1,f2" and same thing applies there.

What i have tried is looking through it as a pointer (unsafe).
But while i can replace character i can't remove them per say.
I guess i have to do without pointers, but i still am not sure how to figure out the rules for the loop even though i kinda grasp it. (the ifs etc to format).

EDIT2:

This is the current Messy code i seem to have gotten to work.

```
    private string FormatCode(string text)
    {

        int length = text.Length;

        char last = '.';

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = text[i];

            if (c == ' ' && last == ',')
            {
                text = text.Remove(i, 1);
                i--;
            }
            else if (c == ',' && last == ' ')
            {
                text = text.Remove(i-1, 1);
                i--;
            }
            else if(c=='(' && last == ' ')
            {
                text = text.Remove(i - 1, 1);
                i--;
            }
            else if(c == ' ' && last == ')')
            {
                text = text.Remove(i, 1);
                i--;
            }
            else if (c == ' ' && last == ' ')
            {
                text = text.Remove(i, 1);
                i--;
            }

            last = c;

        }

        return text;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried doing? Show your efforts and explain why they don't work for you

Comment: @UnholySheep added a bit more:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = "lwz   r4,   -0x0018     (rtoc)";
var b = string.Join(" ", a.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Replace(" ,", ",").Replace(", ", ",")
    .Replace(" (", "(").Replace("( ", "(")
    .Replace(" )", ")").Replace(") ", ")");
```

This variant is faster but longer:

```
var a = "lwz   r4,   -0x0018     ( rtoc )";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.Length);
var spaceFound = false;
var ignoreSpaces = true;
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    if (a[i] == ' ')
        spaceFound = true;
    else if (a[i] == '(' || a[i] == ')' || a[i] == ',')
    {
        sb.Append(a[i]);
        ignoreSpaces = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (spaceFound && !ignoreSpaces)
            sb.Append(' ');
        sb.Append(a[i]);
        spaceFound = false;
        ignoreSpaces = false;
    }
var b = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Sadly the code doesn't always have all these characters, i added another code.

Think those 2 are basically the basic ones, either you have only "," or you have "," and "()",

The amount of "()" and "," can differ, but for most code it's 1-3 "," and 1 "()"

Comment: @Zerowalker I guess it should work for `fmul f0,f1,f2` too.

Comment: Tried it out, it does leave a space around ",".
Compared it to the messy code i made which seems to be quite a bit faster.
However it's not great as it fails if it's a space at "fmul f1,f1,f3 " after f3, it will only make it the same (one spaced) if it's 2 or more)

Comment: @Zerowalker I added a line to skip spaces around `,`.